# Unable to connect to GMail SMTP server

Tags: email-server, gmail, node.js

I'd like to send some emails with my gmail account and nodemailer. Locally, it works fine, but not in my server.

```
$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 465
Trying 74.125.29.108...
Trying 74.125.29.109...
Trying 2607:f8b0:400d:c04::6d...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable

$ openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
connect: Connection timed out

$ nslookup smtp.gmail.com
Server:     8.8.4.4
Address:    8.8.4.4#53

Non-authoritative answer:
smtp.gmail.com  canonical name = gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Name:   gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com
Address: 74.125.29.108
Name:   gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com
Address: 74.125.29.109
```

Comment: Check if you block the host and/or port locally and ask your provider  the same.

Comment: Use port 587 in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your firewall rule(s) allow connection in/out of port 465. If not, try telnetting to another email server to rule out problems with connectivity to gmail in particular (there are many things that could inhibit a connection).

Comment: Thanks Peter, with your and @SvW suggestions I contacted DigitalOcean and it seems that they block SMTP connections by default on new accounts.